# How do I use a database in a custom theme?

Tags: database

I'm new to Wordpress but am creating a custom theme. I don't know much php, but need to store information such as emails, as well as some custom info such as volunteer hours (for specific duties). The email will be stored for a newsletter. What is the easiest way to store this data? Can I use a plugin (despite creating a custom theme?)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, You did not mention if that data will be stored upon submission from front end or you want to manually put that in. But lets see the way I would handle form submissions and store email addresses. I would use contact form 7 along with its addon Flamingo. It will let you store all the email submissions made through the contact form. I hope that is the flow you are looking for.

Also, to insert something into wordpress database, you need to write a simple query, such as:

**Put This Inside your functions.php**

```
global $wpdb; 
$insert_into_database = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare('INSERT INTO your_table_name (column1,column2) VALUES (%s,%d)',array($value_1,$value_2)));
if($insert_into_database){
  // Do something on successfully inserting data.
}
```

Also we are using $wpdb->prepare to prepare our sql for safe execution.

%s – string (value is escaped and wrapped in quotes) 
%d – integer 
%f – float 
%% – % sign

I hope this solves your problem! Cheers :)

Comment: You are mixing up apples with bananas. You can store e-mails independently of the theme. Guessing your need, it sounds like you need some sort of e-mail newsletter plugin. Try "MailPoet" for example. You can choose whatever theme you like, and add the MailPoet plugin with some shortcodes etc.